# kivy opengl segmentation fault on raspberry

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, kivy, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am developing an app on my Raspberry3 with kivy 1.11.0.dev0 and everything was working fine. Last week I bought another Raspberry and since then I am trying to keep the software running on this one without success. I did the same steps on both systems to get kivy running:

- sudo apt-get update
- installation steps from https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-rpi.html

I have no idea why the second one is not working. Both systems are using Raspbian Jessie.

The output of the working one:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-11-02_1.txt
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, 
img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0.dev0, git-0471549, 20180720
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
[GCC 4.9.1]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Broadcom'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'VideoCore IV HW'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event1
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event1>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <b'Lenovo Optical USB Mouse\x00 
...
```

The output of the faulty (with log_level:trace):

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-11-02_9.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0.dev0, git-ad7ec53, 20181102
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
[GCC 4.9.1]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=None
[TRACE  ] [Lang        ] load file /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/data/style.kv
[TRACE  ] [Parser      ] parsing 1291 lines
[TRACE  ] [Parser      ] got directive <kivy 1.0>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Label>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <-Button,-ToggleButton>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <BubbleContent>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <BubbleButton>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Slider>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ProgressBar>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SplitterStrip>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Scatter>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <RelativeLayout>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Image,AsyncImage>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <EffectWidget>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TabbedPanelContent>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TabbedPanelStrip>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <StripLayout>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TabbedPanelHeader>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Selector>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TextInput>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TextInputCutCopyPaste>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <CodeInput>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TreeViewNode>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TreeViewLabel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <StencilView>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <FileChooserListLayout>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <FileChooserListView>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build template for [FileListEntry@FloatLayout+TreeViewNode]
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <FileChooserIconLayout>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <FileChooserIconView>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build template for [FileIconEntry@Widget]
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <FileChooserProgress>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Switch>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ModalView>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Popup>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SpinnerOption>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Spinner>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionBar>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionView>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionSeparator>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionButton,ActionToggleButton>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionLabel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionGroup>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionCheck>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionPreviousImage@Image>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionPreviousButton@Button>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionPrevious>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionGroup>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionOverflow>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionDropDown>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build template for [AccordionItemTitle@Label]
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <AccordionItem>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingSpacer>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingItem>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingBoolean>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingString>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingPath>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingOptions>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingTitle>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingSidebarLabel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingsPanel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Settings>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <InterfaceWithSidebar>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <InterfaceWithSpinner>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <MenuSpinner>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <MenuSidebar>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ContentPanel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <InterfaceWithTabbedPanel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ScrollView>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <VideoPlayerPreview>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <VideoPlayerAnnotation>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <VideoPlayer>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <CheckBox>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ScreenManager>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ColorPicker_Input@TextInput>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ColorPicker_Label@Label>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ColorPicker_Selector@BoxLayout>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ColorWheel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ColorPicker>
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=None
[TRACE  ] [Image       ] Unable to use <gif> as loader!
[TRACE  ] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 129, in core_register_libs
    level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/core/image/img_ffpyplayer.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ffpyplayer
ImportError: No module named 'ffpyplayer'
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[TRACE  ] [Parser      ] parsing 19 lines
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <-CoverBehavior>
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] Loading kv <./test.kv>
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] kv <./test.kv> not found
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Actual display size: 1920x1080
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glActiveTexture is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glAttachShader is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glBindAttribLocation is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glBindBuffer is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glBindFramebuffer is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glBindRenderbuffer is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glBindTexture is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glBlendColor is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glBlendEquation is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glBlendEquationSeparate is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glBlendFunc is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glBlendFuncSeparate is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glBufferData is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glBufferSubData is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glCheckFramebufferStatus is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glClear is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glClearColor is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glClearStencil is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glColorMask is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glCompileShader is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glCompressedTexImage2D is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glCompressedTexSubImage2D is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glCopyTexImage2D is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glCopyTexSubImage2D is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glCreateProgram is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glCreateShader is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glCullFace is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glDeleteBuffers is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glDeleteFramebuffers is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glDeleteProgram is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glDeleteRenderbuffers is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glDeleteShader is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glDeleteTextures is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glDepthFunc is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glDepthMask is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glDetachShader is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glDisable is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glDisableVertexAttribArray is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glDrawArrays is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glDrawElements is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glEnable is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glEnableVertexAttribArray is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glFinish is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glFlush is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glFramebufferRenderbuffer is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glFramebufferTexture2D is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glFrontFace is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGenBuffers is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGenerateMipmap is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGenFramebuffers is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGenRenderbuffers is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGenTextures is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetActiveAttrib is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetActiveUniform is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetAttachedShaders is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetAttribLocation is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetBooleanv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetBufferParameteriv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetError is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetFloatv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetIntegerv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetProgramInfoLog is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetProgramiv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetRenderbufferParameteriv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetShaderInfoLog is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetShaderiv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetShaderSource is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetString is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetTexParameterfv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetTexParameteriv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetUniformfv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetUniformiv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetUniformLocation is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetVertexAttribfv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glGetVertexAttribiv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glHint is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glIsBuffer is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glIsEnabled is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glIsFramebuffer is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glIsProgram is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glIsRenderbuffer is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glIsShader is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glIsTexture is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glLineWidth is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glLinkProgram is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glPixelStorei is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glPolygonOffset is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glReadPixels is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glRenderbufferStorage is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glSampleCoverage is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glScissor is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glShaderBinary is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glShaderSource is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glStencilFunc is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glStencilFuncSeparate is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glStencilMask is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glStencilMaskSeparate is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glStencilOp is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glStencilOpSeparate is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glTexImage2D is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glTexParameterf is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glTexParameteri is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glTexSubImage2D is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform1f is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform1fv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform1i is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform1iv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform2f is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform2fv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform2i is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform2iv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform3f is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform3fv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform3i is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform3iv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform4f is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform4fv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform4i is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniform4iv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUniformMatrix4fv is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glUseProgram is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glValidateProgram is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glVertexAttrib1f is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glVertexAttrib2f is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glVertexAttrib3f is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glVertexAttrib4f is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glVertexAttribPointer is not available
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glViewport is not available
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
```

I also tried to use `sdl2` as window provider. It is working but it's way too laggy and it seems to be not the best solution for me.

After a while it seems to me like it is an OpenGL problem. Changing the raspi-confg brings up these results:

- `OpenGL = G1 GL (Full KMS)`: Result:
  *blackscreen, not working, even not with "startx" on SSH or changing the GPU memory*
- `OpenGL = G2 GL (Fake KMS)`: Result:

  > DEBUG = ... * failed to add service - already in use?
- `OpenGL = G3 Legacy`: Result:

  > DEBUG = ... Segmentation fault

I was trying a lot of stuff like updating firmware with `sudo BRANCH=next rpi-update*` or reinstalling everything several times using old images, new images, python3.5 etc.

From now I have no idea to fix this error. Of cource I can clone the first image but my goal was to have a new, "clean", image

**EDIT**

Like in https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6007 discussed, the problem is the new version/update of Raspbian. I switched back to the old version and now it's running fine!

Another solution could be to use

```
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'gl'
```

Comment: I strongly suggest **not** to update you RPi3, especially the firmware (that include the graphics). Because, and unfortunately, the RPi developer culture is to keep pushing their stuff untested and (what would normally be considered *bleeding edge*) only to try to fix broken things it later, and that is always a lot. If you really wanna try to make it work, you may have better results in downgrading your firmware and keeping to stock distro with default graphics. (Whatever worked before, keep it that way, and send your bug reports to the RPi github dev repo, but don't expect any help!)

Comment: Also, you may get better response to this issue at the [RaspberrySE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). I suggest you double post there. In addition add an issue to their [github repo](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues).

Comment: @not2qubit, you are right, thank you! I updated my post